# Checking if the value of the map has all keys in a triple assigned - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

IF I have a
`Map<Int, Player>`
and a
`Set<Triple<Int, Int, Int>>`

How can I check if one player has all of the ints in one of the triples in the map, for example

````kotlin
setOf(
  Triple(1,2,3),
  Triple(2,6,7),
  Triple(7,9,3)
)
val map = mapOf(
  3 to playerOne
  4 to playerOne
  5 to playerOne
  2 to playerOne
  1 to playerOne
)

// Return true in this scenario, since player has all of the values in one of the triple```
````

```kotlin
setOf(
  Triple(1,2,3),
  Triple(2,6,7),
  Triple(7,9,3)
)

val map = mapOf(
  3 to playerOne
  4 to playerOne
  5 to playerOne
  2 to playerOne
)

// Return false in this case, asthe player does not have all of the numbers in one of the triple
```

Not quite sure if I explained this well aha, but in a nutshell im trying to see if one value in the map has all the values in a Triple

Comment: What is `playerOne` here, and question is unclear for me, do you want to check all the value in one triple is in keys of a map?

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
val set = setOf(
  Triple(1,2,3),
  Triple(2,6,7),
  Triple(7,9,3)
)
val map = mapOf(
  3 to playerOne,
  4 to playerOne,
  5 to playerOne,
  2 to playerOne,
  1 to playerOne
)
val result = set.any { t -> t.toList().all { map[it] == playerOne } }
```

Explanation:
is there any triple `t` inside `set`, where for each element `it` of the triple `t`, value of the map `map` under the key `it` exists and is equal `playerOne`.